# How to do feature selection with rankfeatures?

Tags: matlab, classification

I have tried the following code to select the features in the data. The first two columns represent features and the last column represent classes:

```
clear all;
close all;
data =  [27 9   2
    11.6723281  28.93422177 2
    25  9   2
    23  8   2
    5.896096039 23.97745722 1
    21  6   2
    21.16823369 5.292058423 2
    4.242640687 13.43502884 1
    22  6   2];
Attributes = data(:,1:2);
Classes = data(:,3);
train = [1 3 4 5 6 7];
testInds = [2 8 9];
BC =  Classes  == 2;
I = rankfeatures(data,BC);
```

> Error using rankfeatures (line 208)
>       The length of GROUP must equal the number of columns in X.
>   Error in selection (line 16)
>       I = rankfeatures(data,BC);

Is there any other function to do this???

Comment: size BC should be equal to number of columns in data..i.e there are three columns in data, your BC should be either 1x3 or 3x1.

Comment: how to correct it???? now BC'=[1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1]

Comment: Your BC should be of size 1X3 or 3X1...like BC = [2 1 2]; etc..